# In Magento 2.2 I got this open_basedir restriction in effect error

Tags: directory, magento2.2-dev

From **composer.json**

Am I using the wrong version of Magento.

and i am using  `PHP Version 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4`

**Note: I'm trying to install a theme in it and this work fine on localhost but on live server these issues come**

```
  "name": "magento/magento2ce",
            "description": "Magento 2 (Community Edition)",
            "type": "project",
            "version": "2.2.0-dev",
```

---

```
a:4:{i:0;s:270:"Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/etc/pki/tls/certs) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/:/tmp/) in /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitenamein/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php on line 914";i:1;s:7130:"#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'is_dir(): open_...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 914, Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php(914): is_dir('/etc/pki/tls/ce...')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php(801): Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->getSystemCaRootBundlePath()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php(61): Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->getTlsDefaults(Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php(566): Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->__construct(Object(Composer\IO\BufferIO), Object(Composer\Config), Array, false)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php(306): Composer\Factory::createRemoteFilesystem(Object(Composer\IO\BufferIO), Object(Composer\Config))
#6 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php(532): Composer\Factory->createComposer(Object(Composer\IO\BufferIO), Array, false)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Composer/ComposerFactory.php(47): Composer\Factory::create(Object(Composer\IO\BufferIO), '/var/www/vhosts...')
#8 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php(362): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerFactory->create()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php(375): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation->getComposer()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php(242): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation->getLocker()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/ProductMetadata.php(104): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation->getSystemPackages()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/ProductMetadata.php(65): Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata->getSystemPackageVersion()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/app/code/Magento/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php(208): Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata->getVersion()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/app/code/Magento/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php(138): Magento\AdminNotification\Model\Feed->getFeedData()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/app/code/Magento/AdminNotification/Observer/PredispatchAdminActionControllerObserver.php(51): Magento\AdminNotification\Model\Feed->checkUpdate()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(73): Magento\AdminNotification\Observer\PredispatchAdminActionControllerObserver->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#17 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(61): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\AdminNotification\Observer\PredispatchAdminActionControllerObserver), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#18 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#19 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('controller_acti...', Array)
#20 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action.php(91): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('controller_acti...', Array)
#21 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/AbstractAction.php(227): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#24 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/app/code/Magento/Backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#28 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#31 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#33 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#35 /var/www/vhosts/psweb.in/websitename.in/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#36 {main}";s:3:"url";s:97:"/admin_m2/admin/index/index/key/b817642e7aabbd162a16f487fd1fe8bf169ab304f484a4f83aedabff43a1ff9b/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands to give permission on the folders and to run the composer again.

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf vendor/* app/code/Magento
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
composer install && composer update -vv &&
mage cache:disable &&
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy && 
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```